# media query doesn't pick up new browser size when changing device from portrait to landscape

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to create a website that is "responsive".  I found a tool called "resizemybrowser.com" which tells you what the size of the browser is.  I've been using this information for my media queries inside my css.

What's curious is that when i navigate to this website, the browser width doesn't change when i rotate my device from portrait to landscape.  The height property does show a different value, but the width is always 980px and I don't understand why.

Thank you.

**EDIT 1:**

I also tried to play around with the "outer" setting in the web tool "resizemybrowser.com". now, it does display different sizes for portrait as opposed to landscape mode. It returns 720 for portrait and 1280px for landscape on my galaxy s3.  However, when I test out my media queries using these values, it's still picking up the media query for 720px for both landscape and portrait.  Here's the css:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {        
.hero-unit {
  background: url("../img/1.jpg") 100% 100% no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
width: 20em;
height: 10em;
padding:0px;
    }

  @media only screen and (min-width:721px) and (max-width: 1280px) {        
.hero-unit {
    background: url("../img/2.jpg") 100% 100% no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
width: 26em;
height: 10em;
padding:0px;
    }

      h2 {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

}

EDIT 2

I've tried adding the following line in my code but it didn't make a difference.

```
    <meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width">
```

Compare results [with](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/tests/widthtest_vpdevice.html) this tag and [without](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/tests/widthtest.html), see section **Media queries**. On my device, it works exactly as you want.

Comment: hey there.  i tried addnig that too ... doesn't work.  I've been testing on an iphone 5 and also samsung galaxy s3.  same results.

Comment: Hi, did You get it working finally? I have the same issue. Adding meta tag changes only that, that when I refresh page then it detects correct width. But it requires refresh so its not a solution.